# Struts form and Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, struts

I have a login form in struts and I want to have focus on the username field when the page loads.

I am using `<html:form>` tag and I cannot get this form using its name from javascript as document.formName.username .

How can I do this?

Comment: You should also paste the relevant code, i.e. your form with the textfield on which you're trying to transfer the focus to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot assign id to the form like

/so the best way to do this is to access a particular form in a sequence it appears. Same is the sequence case for form elements.

```
document.forms[0].elements[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign an id to the input element that you want to focus on, then do:

`document.getElementById("myInputId").focus();`

Alternately, don't give it an id, and do:

`document.getElementsByName("username")[0].focus();`

Comment: We cannot assign id to the form like <html:form id="formName"> 

/so the best way to do this is to access a particular form in a sequence it appears. Same is the ssequence case for form elements.

    document.forms[0].elements[0]

Comment: @imran, no, id is set when you specify a name to your action in `struts-config.xml` (use `<html:html xhtml="true">` if your `<html:form>` doesn't render an `id` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

if you have `<html:form action="/someAction">` and in your `struts-config.xml`, you've specified a `name` for that action (which points to an `ActionForm`) and your html declaration is `<html:html xhtml="true">` and inside your form you have `<html:input>` (with name of "userName"), then you can do this in your javascript:

```
document.formName.userName.value;
```

else

```
document.forms["formName"].userName.value;
```

Comment: We cannot assign id to the form like <html:form id="formName"> 

/so the best way to do this is to access a particular form in a sequence it appears. Same is the sequence case for form elements.

    document.forms[0].elements[0]

Comment: @imran, no, id is set when you specify a name to your action in `struts-config.xml` (use `<html:html xhtml="true">` if your `<html:form>` doesn't render an `id` attribute.